# MVC Validation make RegularExpression numeric only on string field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following property in my view model:

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(12)]
[MinLength(1)]
[RegularExpression("[^0-9]", ErrorMessage = "UPRN must be numeric")]
public string Uprn { get; set; }
```

Regardless of `Uprn` being a `string`, I want to throw a validation error if there is anything other than numbers entered into the Uprn box on page submit.

With the above, I am getting the error "UPRN must be numeric" whether its a string or int

What's going on here?

Comment: Is your property an array? It is just a string in your code snippet?

Comment: sorry I just just meant an array as in 1234 or hello

Comment: To clarify why the regex is wrong, `^` inside `[]` means *not* - so you're saying: allow anything *except numbers*.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The regular expression is wrong. Replace it with:

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(12)]
[MinLength(1)]
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "UPRN must be numeric")]
public string Uprn { get; set; }
```

Don't forget to include:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

in your view for the jquery validation

Answer (score 10):

Or you could do the length validation in the regexp:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]{1,12}$", ErrorMessage = "...")]
public string Uprn { get; set; }
```

Here's the regex visualized:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7s_BpAzblfS-tE1P)

Comment: This way you would only have one error message, separated out you can specify different error messages per condition :)

Answer (score 7):

The RegEx should be `^[0-9]*$`.

I.E.

The property should look like:

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(12)]
[MinLength(1)]
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "UPRN must be numeric")]
public string Uprn { get; set; }
```

See working [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GddtP8).

---

I'm sure you already have jQuery referenced but make sure jQuery validate and Microsoft validate scripts are included.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use either:

```
[RegularExpression("\d*", ErrorMessage = "UPRN must be numeric")]
```

*note that it will accept empty if you remove [Required] and [MinLength(1)]

or use the following:

```
[RegularExpression("\d+", ErrorMessage = "UPRN must be numeric")]
```

which will only accept one more digits

you can test your regular expressions here:     https://regex101.com/

Comment: This will accept alphanumeric characters. Use "^[\d]*$ " to restrict to numeric only