# Make input field validate a number range and a single character using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

This is a commonly asked question. But I am not getting the answer that I need. I had a look at [MVC Validation make RegularExpression numeric only on string field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532161/mvc-validation-make-regularexpression-numeric-only-on-string-field) (among many) for reference but I am not quite there yet.

I have an html5 input field bound to an MVC property. I want to make use of the `[RegularExpression()]` attribute but I am not getting the output that I need. I need my input to **only** take the following:

A single number between `0` and `7`, **or** the `%` character

I tried the following:

`[RegularExpression("^[0-7][%]")]`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Any number of numbers and the `%`? (you currently allow only a single number (0-7) followed by `%`

Comment: The input field should only take a single value whether its a number in the range `0-7` or the `%` character

Comment: You need an OR - `^[0-7]|[%]$`

Comment: @StephenMuecke That worked. You can mark your comment as an answer

Comment: Answers have already been added :) - but I'll update you question to make it clear what you wanted.

Comment: Actually, the context free regex will look like `^(?:[0-7]|%)$` or even better, `^[0-7%]$` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49023809/3832970)). However, if the pattern is only used in the HTML5 pattern attribute, the `^` and `$` might be redundant, and really, `[0-7]|%` or `[0-7]|%` will also work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use **range from 0 to 7. (Only single digit at a time)** then use `[0-7]` and for **%** use `[%]`. To concatenate both the requirements(For or condition) use `|` in between two square brackets.

Your regular expression would be look like this

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-7]|[%]")]
```

`^` at the starting of regular expressions, suggests that your string should starts with the number.

`$` mentioned by @Stephen in comments states that your `%` must occurs at the end of string or expression.

Now its up to you, **if you want string should be in D% format, where D is for digit and %**, **then use ^ in the beginning and $ at the end of regex**. e.g. 5%

if **this is not the case, then you can remove ^ and $ from the regex** e.g  `%`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Can I share my points with you. You were faster than me